# IIS and SQL Server Windows authentication in a django application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, django, iis, windows-authentication

I am trying to run a django website which connects to a SQL Server, using IIS with Windows authentication.

IIS server and SQL server are on different machines under the same domain i.e., ***iis_machine.example.com*** and ***sql_machine.example.com***

***What I'm trying to achieve***:

1. Impersonate the remote user accessing the django website hosted on
   IIS, so his Windows credentials are passed to SQL Server for
   authentication.

***What I tried so far***:

1. Added this to my web.config file for impersonation

   `<system.web>
   <identity impersonate="true" />
   </system.web>`
2. Enabled Windows authentication and set up Application Pool (django_web) for django website as shown below

   [This is what my Authentication for django website looks like in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuGYA.png)

   [This is what my Application Pool for django website looks like in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8afP.png)
3. Added ***IIS APPPOOL\django_web*** to SQL Server ***Security\Logins***

**Result**:

1. When I access the django website, IIS prompts the user for his
   Windows credentials and I can successfully login
2. If user tries to access SQL Server after logging in

   *Case a*. IIS, SQL Server are on the different machines: SQL server authentication fails with
   "***Login failed for user 'domain\MACHINENAME$***'

   *Case b*. IIS, SQL Server are on the same machine, SQL server authentication is successful but authentication credentials used are ***IIS APPPOOL\django_web*** not ***domain\remote_user***

I understand that there is some Kerberos trickery involved with this setup. Unfortunately, I'm only a programmer and not very familiar with how Kerberos works. If someone experienced in this domain, could shed some light on how this setup would work, that'd be really appreciated. Thanks!

I am using:

- IIS 10 SQL
- Server 2014
- django 2.0.7
- Python 3.6.5
- Windows 8/10

Comment: did you manage to solve that problem?

Comment: I think I am experiencing the exact same problem. Is there any progress on this problem?